# Управление процессами или одно задание на всех

Tags: python

Есть N-е количество процессов (не важно, треды, форки или просто программы). Им всем надо передать какую-то информацию, например, о неком событии. То есть, нужно чтобы было одно место, откуда они все должны брать информацию.
Как это обычно реализуется?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ищите в сторону словосочетаний «publish-subscribe» и «message bus.» Там много можно найти вариантов, выбирайте на вкус и под задачу.

Например,

- Если похитрее, и чтобы с очередями и подтверждением доставки — AMQP-сервер, скажем, RabbitMQ. Или не AMQP а STOMP использовать.
- Если более примитивно — Redis, например, да.
- Опять же, иногда все уже есть в системе. Например, часто можно встретить D-Bus на *nix'овых десктопах. Правда D-Bus по сети — это (хоть и возможно) очень, очень через задницу и только после огромного напильника, так что решение только в пределах одной машины.
- А если в конторе есть XMPP-сервер — оно тоже можо использовать.
- Если без сервера — у 0MQ (aka ZeroMQ) есть pub/sub возможности.
- Или вообще старые добрые (но малоизвестные) POSIX message queues, если надо в пределах одной машины.

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку - через пайпы. Можете посмотреть, как это реализовано, например в [**Google Test.**](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) Там каждый тест запускается в отдельном процессе и весь `interop` с главным процессом происходит через `pipes` *(естественно, кроссплатформенно).*

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что у Redis-а есть подобная функция.